# Authenticating automatically to a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a web site I would like to log in to and display in a WebBrowser control by passing a username and password which the client desktop application already has.

What would be the best and most secure way to go about doing this?

Can I make a Web Service to authenticate and then somehow pass the Session to the browser control? I am using Forms Authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at OAuth: http://oauth.net/

Comment: Has it got less non-trivial since the last time I looked at it?

Answer (score 0):

The `WebBrowser` control will share the WinInet session of your process. If your application makes an HTTP request to authenticate, and the site sets the proper auth cookie in the session, the `WebBrowser` control should pick it up properly.

You still have the problem of how to pass the credentials to the website in a secure manner, of course.